# How do I use the GTranslate module?

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

I have installed the [GTranslate](http://drupal.org/project/gtranslate) module, and I am searching for how to use it. In the module page, the language selection drop-down box is there, but when I installed this module the drop-down list didn't appear. How do I use the GTranslate module?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Translate changed their policy, this module does not work anymore according to the issue queue.

There seems to be a newer version on an external website, which also offers a paid Pro version that seems to require ioncube encoder which means that it is encrypted, which sounds like a violation of the GPL to me.

Comment: Any free automatic translation (node) module available in Drupal ?